# Javascript: .reset is causing page to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
 <form class="controls" id="Filters">
<fieldset>
    <div id="sample-showcase" class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background"></div>
    <div id="rangespan-container">
        <span id="min-value-span" class="range-spans"></span>
                    <input type="hidden" class="min-value-span">
        <span class="range-spans">g</span>
        <span id="max" class="range-spans"> - </span>
        <span id="max-value-span" class="range-spans"></span>
                    <input type="hidden" class="min-value-span">
        <span class="range-spans">g</span>
    </div>
    <div class="range-button checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="rangecheck"/></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <h3 class="sidetitle">Filter</h3>
    <div class="breakfast-filter checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value=".category-breakfast"/>
                     <label>Breakfast</label></div> 
    <div class="lunch-filter checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" value=".category-lunch"/>
                     <label>Lunch</label></div> 
    <div class="dinner-filter checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox3" value=".category-dinner"/>
                     <label>Dinner</label></div>    
    <div class="snacks-filter checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox4" value=".category-snacks"/>
                    <label>Snacks</label></div> 
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <h3 class="sidetitle">Sort</h3>
    <div class="sort" data-sort="protein:asc">Low to High</div>
    <div class="sort" data-sort="protein:desc">High to Low</div>
    <div class="sort" data-sort="random">Random</div>
</fieldset>

<button id="Reset">Clear Filters</button>
</form>
```

**Snippet of JS**

```
bindHandlers: function(){
var self = this;

self.$filters.on('change', function(){
  self.parseFilters();
});

self.$reset.on('click', function(){
  self.$filters[0].reset();
  self.parseFilters();
});
}
```

`self.$reset = jQuery('#Reset');` it is defined higher in the code. Not sure if this is enough info.

**Here is the link to the full code:** [Click Here](http://tammymealplan.com/code/)

If you go to the home page click on some filters then try resetting. You should see it work like it's suppose to then take you to domain.com/?

Not sure why

Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`button` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) are submit buttons by default. You have to set `type="button"` if you to make them "dummy" buttons, i.e. they don't have a any default behavior:

> `type="button"`: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

```
<button type="button" id="Reset">Clear Filters</button>
```

---

Of course you could also set it to `type="reset"` and let the browser take care of resetting the form elements for you:

> `type="reset"`: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.

Then you could simplify your event handler to:

```
self.$reset.on('click', function(){
  self.parseFilters();
});
```

It's not a huge change, but if the browser already offers this feature, why not make use of it?

Comment: @felix kling. Just a small correction, the default type is not submit for IE 7 and below, though it holds true for all the latest browsers :)

Comment: @rakhi4110: I didn't know that! But it's also not surprising that older IE versions don't follow standards ;) http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5 (and that was 15 years ago!)

Comment: @FelixKling. Correct. I did go through this. But when i practically tried it in older browsers, they dont seem to behave accordingly. And as you said, it is no suprise though :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a button within the form and it is not prevented its default behavior.
Hence after resetting the form, the form is getting submitted.

You either have to return false after the function or preventDefault(). Try this.

```
self.$reset.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  self.$filters[0].reset();
  self.parseFilters();
});
```

Or you need to set the type="button" for the button tag to make sure they are of type button and not submit.

```
<button id="Reset" type="button">Clear Filters</button>
```